# How to run self referenced method from dictionary in python class?

Tags: python, python-class

So, is there a method to define self referencing dictionary of lambda functions which can be used to call different methods based upon the keys?
Consider a small example of what is intended?

```
class A:
    d = {
        "add": lambda p1, p2: self.add(p1, p2),
        "minus": lambda p1, p2: self.minus(p1, p2),
        "multiply": lambda p1, p2: self.multiply(p1, p2),
        "divide": lambda p1, p2: self.divide(p1, p2)
    }
    def add(self, p1, p2):
        return p1+p2
    def minus(self, p1, p2):
        return p1-p2
    def multiply(self, p1, p2):
        return p1*p2
    def divide(self, p1, p2):
        return p1/p2
```

If I try the following:

```
a = A()
a.d["add"](1,2)
```

The above line throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

What can be the best method to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, your `add`, `minus`, etc. methods can be static, hence not require the instance of `A`, so your lambdas would be `"add": lambda p1, p2: A.add(p1, p2)`, etc:

```
class A:
    d = {
        "add": lambda p1, p2: A.add(p1, p2),
        "minus": lambda p1, p2: A.minus(p1, p2),
        "multiply": lambda p1, p2: A.multiply(p1, p2),
        "divide": lambda p1, p2: A.divide(p1, p2)
    }

    @staticmethod
    def add(p1, p2):
        return p1+p2

    @staticmethod    
    def minus(p1, p2):
        return p1-p2

    @staticmethod
    def multiply(p1, p2):
        return p1*p2

    @staticmethod
    def divide(p1, p2):
        return p1/p2
```

As your `d` dictionary is static (class field) you can't call the instance methods. You could if you initialized it in the `__init__` of `A`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {
            "add": lambda p1, p2: self.add(p1, p2),
            "minus": lambda p1, p2: self.minus(p1, p2),
            "multiply": lambda p1, p2: self.multiply(p1, p2),
            "divide": lambda p1, p2: self.divide(p1, p2)
        }
    def add(self, p1, p2):
        return p1+p2

    def minus(self, p1, p2):
        return p1-p2

    def multiply(self, p1, p2):
        return p1*p2

    def divide(self, p1, p2):
        return p1/p2
```

In both cases

```
a = A()
a.d["add"](1,2)
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the functions in the dictionary to be bound to the instance, then you need a dictionary *per instance*, so the dictionary needs to be initialised in the `__init__` method. The way you have it right now, your dictionary is a class attribute, so you have a single dictionary shared by all instances, and it's initialised when the class is declared, which is before any instances exist.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {
            "add": lambda p1, p2: self.add(p1, p2),
            "minus": lambda p1, p2: self.minus(p1, p2),
            "multiply": lambda p1, p2: self.multiply(p1, p2),
            "divide": lambda p1, p2: self.divide(p1, p2),
        }
    def add(self, p1, p2):
        return p1+p2
    def minus(self, p1, p2):
        return p1-p2
    def multiply(self, p1, p2):
        return p1*p2
    def divide(self, p1, p2):
        return p1/p2
```

Note that you don't need to use `lambda` functions if you just want bound methods; you can reference the bound methods directly, like this:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {
            "add": self.add,
            "minus": self.minus,
            "multiply": self.multiply,
            "divide": self.divide,
        }
    ...
    # the rest is the same
```